# PHPSpreadsheet 1.2.1 Exception Invalid cell coordinate on Load

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Getting the following error when loading an existing spreadsheet:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception: 100!C5 -> Invalid cell
>   coordinate B in
>   /var/www/spreadsheet/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.php:274

Formula is:

```
=LOOKUP(E5,'GeoCodes'!B:B,'GeoCodes'!A:A)
```

Which does a lookup value in E5 in worksheet 'GeoCodes' column B, return 'GeoCodes' value in column A.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is due to the non-static range values 'B:B' and 'A:A'. Switching to a static value of B<1>:B<1000> and A<1>:A<1000> corrects the issue.